# Equations differential systems.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

Can you help me to solve this equation.
How could solve it? 
$$x'_1=-2x_1-x_2$$
$$x'_2=4x_1-2x_2-2t^{-3}$$

Comment: @ Iuli: are you sure that there is no missprint in the term $-2t^{-3}$ because it will introduce complicated functions into the solution : special function Ei$(z)$. Except this point, the solution is not complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isolate $x_2$ from the first equation and replace all the terms where $x_2$ and its derivative appear as a function of $x_1$. You should end with a second order differential equation in $x_1$; solve it and when you will know $x_1$, $x_2$ will be given by the first equation you used.